# My unsynced Safari Tabs on macOS Monterey disappeared after using my iPad, is there a way to recover?

Tags: macos, ipad, safari, data-synchronization, mobile-safari

I'm on the latest version of Monterey and latest version of iPadOS

I opened a few dozen tabs in Safari over the week so I decided to put them all into my main tab group, which already had a few tabs that I was saving from last week, from when I last picked my iPad.

They didn't sync over when I picked up my iPad last night but I thought nothing of it.

When I woke up today and opened my Mac, I saw that all the many dozens of tabs had disappeared. With only the few tabs from last week left.

I figure the sync process must not only have failed last night, but also failed in the wrong direction thus erasing all the newer tabs.

I can't find any quick way to recover them, as none of the standard methods work. They are still in my history, but that would mean going over thousands of pages.

Is there any way to recover the disappeared tabs?